# Javascript 'console' infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, freeze

I'm experimenting with javascript programs and I hit a snag. The program suddenly lags my browser (infinite loop maybe), dunno why.

```
function fullscreen() {
    if (document.body.requestFullScreen) {document.body.requestFullScreen();}
    else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen) {document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen();}
    else if (document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) {document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();}
}

var bash = document.createElement('span');
bash.setAttribute('id', 'bash');
document.body.appendChild(bash);

var cursor = document.createElement('span');
cursor.setAttribute('id', 'bashCursor');
cursor.textContent = '_';
cursor.style.display = 'none';
cursor.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
document.body.appendChild(cursor);

window.Bash = {};
window.Bash.printing = false;
window.Bash.queue = Array();
window.Bash.span = bash;
window.Bash.span.cursor = cursor;

delete bash; delete bash;


function bashPrint() {
    window.Bash.writing = true;
    var bash = window.Bash.span
    var i;
    while (window.Bash.queue.length) {
        if (window.Bash.queue[0] == undefined) {
            i = 0;
            while (i < window.Bash.queue.length) {
                window.Bash.queue[i] = window.Bash.queue[i+1];
                console.log('l:'+window.Bash.queue.length);
                console.log(window.Bash.queue);
                delete window.Bash.queue[i+1];
                window.Bash.queue.splice(i,1);
                i++;
            }

        } else if (window.Bash.queue[0]['type'] == 'instant') {
            bash.textContent += window.Bash.queue[0]['value'];
            delete window.Bash.queue[0];
            window.Bash.queue.splice(0,1);

        } else if (window.Bash.queue[0]['type'] == 'wait') {
            setTimeout(bashPrintWaiting, window.Bash.queue[0]['wait']);
            break;

        } else if (window.Bash.queue[0]['type'] == 'cursor') {
            if (window.Bash.queue[0]['value']) {
                window.Bash.span.cursor.style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                window.Bash.span.cursor.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    window.Bash.writing = false;
}

function bashPrintWaiting() {
    window.Bash.writing = true;
    var bash = window.Bash.span;
    bash.textContent += window.Bash.queue[0]['value'];
    delete window.Bash.queue[0];
    window.Bash.queue.splice(0,1);
    window.Bash.writing = false;
    setTimeout(bashPrint, 0);
}

function bashWrite(string) {
    var array = Array();
    array['type'] = 'instant';
    array['value'] = string;
    window.Bash.queue[window.Bash.queue.length] = array
}

function bashPause(times, string) {
    if (!string) {string='';}
    while (times > 0) {
        var array = Array();
        array['type'] = 'wait';
        array['value'] = string;
        array['wait'] = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random()*450);
        window.Bash.queue[window.Bash.queue.length] = array;
        times--;
    }
}

function bashCursor(enabled) {
    var array = Array();
    array['type'] = 'cursor';
    array['value'] = enabled;
    window.Bash.queue[window.Bash.queue.length] = array;
}

bashWrite('Uncompressing');
bashPause(12, '.');
bashWrite('OK\n');

bashPause(3);
bashWrite('Build v. 0.1.01-release (x86_64-pc)\n');

bashPause(2);
bashWrite('Connecting');
bashPause(35, '.');
bashWrite('Error, unknown user. See connect.log for futher information.\n');

bashPause(2);
bashWrite('none@m ~ $ >>');
bashCursor(true);

bashPrint();
```

I uploaded it on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uQcCP/

Program freezes between:

```
bashWrite('Error, unknown user. See connect.log for futher information.\n');
```

and

```
bashPause(2);
```

Please, can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Obvious warning: The JSFiddle will hang your browser.

Comment: Always post the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: That's why you have a dev Chrome handy... :P

Comment: Could you please make it so that the code will not start running, or paste the code someplace else like pastebin? It's a bit hard to debug something that freezes the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite loop starts on line 51: `while (window.Bash.queue.length) {`

It then ends up in the if statement on line 74, and within this the queue is never shortened:

```
else if (window.Bash.queue[0]['type'] == 'cursor') {
   if (window.Bash.queue[0]['value']) {
      window.Bash.span.cursor.style.display = 'inline';
```

If you find yourself having infinite loop problems in Chrome, open up your development tools and go to the script tab before you open up the page. After you open up the page and it starts looping, you can click the pause button to throw a breakpoint wherever the code is currently executing. From there it's a lot easier to divine where you're getting your error.

Comment: @m93a You're welcome! I added some information on how I debugged it if you're interested.

Comment: Did not know about the pause button. Excellent, addition!